# XML-сериализация объекта с полем типа Object C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialize, объекты, полиморфизм

Как (де)сериализовать объект в котом есть поле Value типа Object. Это объект супер-класса, где конкретные реализации класса отличаются только поведением.
Пример:

```
class Tag
{
  public object Value {get;set;}

  public virtual void SomeMethod();
}

class Tag: TableTag 
{
  public object Value 
  {
   get 
   {
    return Value as DataTable; 
   }
  ...
}
```

Пытаюсь сериализовать как обычно:

```
        var lst = new myTagCollection();
        lst.Collection = new List<Tag>();
        lst.Collection.Add(t1);
        lst.Collection.Add(t2);
        lst.Collection.Add(t3);
        string testName = "lst.xml";

        Stream saveStream = File.Open(testName, FileMode.Truncate);

        XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myTagCollection), new Type[] { typeof(TableTag), typeof(TextTag), typeof(PictTag), typeof(DataTable) });
        if (saveStream != null)
        {
            formatter.Serialize(saveStream, lst);
            saveStream.Close();
        }
```

> Результат Сообщение:
>   Метод проверки WRC.Test.TagTesting.XMLSerializeTagTast выдал исключение: 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Ошибка при создании документа XML. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Тип "System.Data.DataTable" не может использоваться в этом контексте. Чтобы использовать System.Data.DataTable в качестве параметра, возвращаемого типа, члена класса или структуры, параметр, возвращаемый тип или член должны быть объявлены, как имеющие тип System.Data.DataTable (не может являться объектом). Объекты типа System.Data.DataTable не могут использоваться в коллекциях без типа, например ArrayLists..

В связи с этим вопрос: что делаю не так? И как можно сериализовать объекты типа Tag и неким полем типа object, если заранее не известно какой конкретной реализацией (TableTag, PictTag, TextTag) он будет инициализирован?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как можно сериализовать объекты типа Tag и неким полем типа object, если заранее не известно какой конкретной реализацией (TableTag, PictTag, TextTag) он будет инициализирован

Невозможно, это ограничение XML-сериализации в .NET. Вы должны *точно* знать при компиляции, какие именно типы будут десериализироваться.

В вашем случае, возможно, подойдёт такой код:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(TableTag)),
 XmlInclude(typeof(PictTag)),
 XmlInclude(typeof(TextTag))]
abstract class Tag
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    abstract object Value { get; }
}

class TableTag : Tag
{
    public DataTable TableValue { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public override object Value { get { return TableValue; } }
}
```