# Не работает сериализация объекта из xml в string C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, xml, serialize

**Рутовый класс:**

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Main")]
public class MainClass
{
    public MainClass()
    {
        Parents = new List<MyParent>();
    }

    [XmlElement("Parent")]
    public List<MyParent> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

**Есть родительский класс:**

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Parent")]
public class MyParent
{
    public enum myEnum : int
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    };

    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Есть класс, расширяющий его:**

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Parent")]
public class MyChild : MyParent
{
    public MyChild()
    {
        Child = new List<InnerParameter>();
    }

    [XmlElement("Child")]
    public List<InnerParameter> Child { get; set; }
}
```

**Этот класс раскрывает, что внутри тега Child**:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Child")]
public class InnerParameter
{
    public InnerParameter()
    {

    }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Затем, пытаюсь сериализовать:**

```
MainClass newMainXml = new MainClass();
newMainXml.Parents = new List<MyParent>();
MyChild ch = new MyChild ();

ch.Id = "123";
ch.Name = "Stefani";

InnerParameter parameter = new InnerParameter();
parameter.Value = "MyText";
ch.Child.Add(parameter);

newMainXml.Parents.Add(ch);

XmlSerialization.TrySerializeObjectToXmlString(newMainXml, out result);
```

**Хочу на выходе такую XML:**

```
<Main>
    <Parent Id="123" Name="Stefani">
        <Child>MyText</Child>
    </Parent>
</Main>
```

**Получаю ошибку сериализации:**

*There was an error generating the XML document. The type **MyChild** was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.*

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так в формировании xml? Почему сериализация не работает? (**Есть большое подозрение, что дело тут в наследовании и зависимости классов между собой. Наверно, надо сказать, что MyChild не единственный класс, который расширяет MyParent...**)

**P.S.:** похоже, что тут ситуация как у меня почти: [XML-сериализация объекта с полем типа Object C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445376/xml-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-object-c?rq=1)

Comment: Как насчет того, чтобы добавить текст ошибки и стектрейс?

Comment: `XmlSerialization.TrySerializeObjectToXmlString` не выглядит как стандартный метод. Покажите его реализацию.

Comment: @andreycha, отредактировал вопрос. Добавил текст ошибки.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [XML-сериализация объекта с полем типа Object C#](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/445376/xml-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-object-c)

Comment: Да, ситуация у вас как в аналогичном вопросе. Вам нужно добавить `XmlInclude`.

Comment: @andreycha, добавил - не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решается действительно добавлением **[XmlInclude(typeof(MyChild))]** таким образом:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Parent")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(MyChild))]
public class MyParent
{
    public enum myEnum : int
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    };

    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Моя ошибка была в том, что (для сравнения) у меня было написано так:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Parent")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(MyChild)),
 XmlInclude(typeof(HisChild)),
 XmlInclude(typeof(HerChild))]
public class MyParent
{
    public enum myEnum : int
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    };

    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Однако, как я уже говорил, **MyChild** - не единственный класс, реализующий **MyParent**, и эти наследники так же необходимо сериализовать. Вот тут хорошая статья: [Xml Сериализация и наследование](http://www.cyberguru.ru/dotnet/net-framework/xml-serialization-f2-page4.html)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так :)

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ch = new MyChild();
        ch.Id = "123";
        ch.Name = "Stefani";
        var parameter = new InnerParameter();
        parameter.Value = "MyText";
        ch.Child.Add(parameter);
        string result = XmlHelper.ObjectToXmlString(ch);
    }

    public static class XmlHelper
    {
        public static string ObjectToXmlString(object obj)
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, obj);
                return textWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Т.к. был отредактирован вопрос - вот новое решение исправления ошибки, которое выдает Ваш код:

```
[Serializable, XmlInclude(typeof(MyChild))]
[XmlRoot("Main")]
```

Просто добавьте XmlInclude(typeof(MyChild)) для класса MainClass, т.к. он ничего не знает о MyChild это позволит ему распознать MyChild в процессе сериализации.

Comment: Уверен, автор вопроса был бы признателен вам за комментарии и пояснение идеи решения.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, да, в принципе, без пояснений всё довольно понятно. Функция **ObjectToXmlString(object obj)** очень похожа на ту, которую я использую, просто я не привёл её код.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения!

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему `TrySerializeObjectToXmlString` у вас реализован примерно так:

```
private static void TrySerializeObjectToXmlString(MainClass ch, out string result)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    using (var writer = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MainClass));
        s.Serialize(writer, ch);
    }
    result = sb.ToString();
}
```

С такой реализацией он падает именно с ошибкой из вопроса.

В таком случае должно хватить добавления `XmlInclude` на тип `MyParent`:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Command")]
[XmlInclude(typeof(MyChild))]
public class MyParent
{
    public enum myEnum : int
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three
    };

    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Не помогло.....

Comment: @neo я полностью скопировал ваш код из вопроса, добавил метод TrySerializeObjectToXmlString, запустил - упало. Добавил XmlInclude - заработало. Вот ссылка на gist с полным кодом примера: https://gist.github.com/PashaPash/e725653863c615437be7

Comment: похоже, что проблема сокрыта не в этой части кода... Сейчас попробую воссоздать в вопросе более сложную картину...

Comment: отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: @neo код из обновленного вопроса не копмпилируется. а если добавить скобки - все еще работает. приведите минимальный **воспроизводимый** пример

Comment: почему не компилируется? Что пишет? Это как раз минимальный.

Comment: @neo он не минимальный, но не воспроизводимый. во первых там просто нет скобок в `new List<MyParent>`. во вторых переменная `newMainXml ` не используется - потому что вы сериализуете `ch`, а не `newMainXml`. В третьих покажите код вашего `TrySerializeObjectToXmlString` - от него реально зависит результат. Какой параметр он принимает первым? Какой тип используется при создании сериализатора? например, если заменить в моем примере выше именно в этом методе два упоминания `MyParent ` на `MyChild` - то будет работать и без XmlInclude.

Comment: @neo т.е. практически вы предлагаете всем угадать что ж у вас там написано не так, как в вопросе или моем ответе. гист же рабочий. по сути, он ничем от вашего приведенного кода не отличается, кроме неиспользованной переменной - значит вы не привели весь код.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34556/discussion-between-neo-and-pashapash).